# Change symbol while typing and continue typing

Tags: c#, replace

I have to replace every `,` with `.` and to be able to continue typing.
I'm using this code below and it works but the cursor is placed at the front of the text.

```
private void textBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox7.Text = textBox7.Text.Replace(",",".");
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this? I want to be able to continue typing after the replacement.

Comment: [**This**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752349(v=vs.100).aspx) might help you.

Comment: Are you sure that's the code you're using? `textBox7.Text.Replace(",",".')` won't change the text in the text box. You have to assign the result of that method call to something.

Comment: @JimMischel Ops, I missed textBox7.Text =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the KeyPress event you can change the character on the fly:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyChar == ',')
        {
            e.KeyChar = '.';
        }
    }
```

This will echo the new character instead of the typed one and the user can keep typing.

Comment: @user3473957 Did you add the event handler properly?  You can't just copy and paste the code.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @kei

```
   private void textBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       textBox7.Text = textBox7.Text.Replace(",",".");
       textBox7.Select(textBox7.Text.Length, 0);
    }
```

The simplest way and exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, taking consideration for typing in the middle of the TextBox

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var t = (sender as TextBox);
        var s = t.Text.IndexOf(",");
        if (s > -1)
        {
            t.Text = t.Text.Replace(",", ".");
            t.SelectionStart = s+1;
        }
    }
```

But there may be other considerations, such as pasting text